# Nested asynchronous blocks of code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, concurrency

I am trying to nest a `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` call inside of an asynchronous `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest` in Swift 2.0, but the code block inside of the `test` does not seem to get evaluated.

For example:

```
class testc{

    @objc func test()
    {
        print("hello");
    }

    func loop()
    {
        if let url = NSURL(string : "https://www.google.com")
        {
            let url_req = NSURLRequest(URL: url);

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(url_req)
            { data, response, error in

                 let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(testc.test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            }

            task.resume()

        }


    }
}
```

If we initialize this class and run `loop` nothing happens, the function `test` **was never evaluated**.

Comment: You forgot  task.resume()

Comment: Whoops that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: you do not have the correct well, look my answer

Comment: put it at the end of the task, not at the end of the function

Comment: You're right but I still get no calls to the `test` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two changes to your code.

After creating the dataTask. You need to ask it to resume() to send the request.
The timer needs to be called on the main thread.

In your case, the dataTask is an asynchrnous task that runs on a background thread. In the implementation below, we are jumping back to the main thread to fire the timer.

I have added a counter to verify if the timer is firing repeatedly.

See updated code below.

```
    class testc{

    static var counter : Int = 0

    @objc func test()
    {   testc.counter++
        print("hello -> \(testc.counter)");
    }

    func loop()
    {
        if let url = NSURL(string : "https://www.google.com")
        {
            let url_req = NSURLRequest(URL: url);

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(url_req){ data, response, error in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                    self.setupTimer()
                })

            }.resume()
        }
    }

    func setupTimer() {
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(testc.test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}


let theBoy = testc()

theBoy.loop()
```

Comment: The timer seems to fire only once when I run it, `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` should fire indefinitely shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, please see updated answer. The timer needs to be setup  and fired on the main thread.